# Change MacOS X guest screen resolution for VirtualBox

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have tried all alternatives and resources that I found on internet to achieve to change screen resolution in my MacOS X guest. I have the latest VirtualBox version (4.1.22) and I have MacOS X 10.6.3 Snow Leopard running in a vm guest.

Some solutions that don't work for me are:

- Tuning virtual machine settings:

Adding  and  in the .vbox file, or running these two commands:

```
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32"
vboxmanage setextradata "MAC OS X" "GUI/CustomVideoMode1" "1360x768x32"
```

- Editing Guest OS boot configuration:

Modify /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.boot.plist with these lines:

```
<key>Kernel Flags</key>
<string>"Graphics Mode"="1360x768x32"</string>
<key>Graphics Mode</key>
<string>1360x768x32</string>
```

Any other suggestion, something that I was missing.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Anybody can help me and tell me what would be the StackOverflow family web to put this question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm battling this as well. I've seen a third option mentioned [in some places](http://www.sysprobs.com/increase-mac-os-virtual-machine-screen-resolution-virtualbox-vmware-player): in addition to the `CustomVideoMode1` there's a `VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode` parameter which can be set to one of six fixed resolutions:

`VBoxManage setextradata "vmname" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode 3`

The possible values for EfiGopMode are:

```
0: 640x480  
1: 800x600  
2: 1024x768  
3: 1280x1024 
4: 1440x900
5: 1920x1200
```

Not tried this method yet myself because I want to go to 1600x1200...

Comment: Thank you Ola, but this qüestion was closed (off topic), my wanted resolution would be 1280x800. This mode not appear in this 5 fixed resolutions, any alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Only the ones you already mentioned in your question. FWIW I eventually settled for 1280x1024 using EfiGopMode and got on with it. The lack of graphics drivers for OS X under VirtualBox makes for pretty crappy 2D performance anyway (someone should make one based on the VirtualBox open source driver) - but it's good enough for testing websites with, which is my main use of this set-up.

Comment: And you can add 5: 1920x1200 https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efividmode

Comment: @heralight: Ah, good find, thanks for the update!

Comment: No way for custom ones? need 1080

Comment: @Hamzah I _think_ OS X will only run using EFI modes under VirtualBox, which would limit you to the list given above - though I may well be wrong, and this may have changed since my original reply. I no longer use VB for OS X emulation - in fact I hardly use virtualisation _at all_ any more, other than on the server side - you may have better luck getting a definite answer by starting a new question.

Comment: From the Virtualbox Manual
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html
3.13.1. Video modes in EFI

EFI provides two distinct video interfaces: GOP (Graphics Output Protocol) and UGA (Universal Graphics Adapter). Mac OS X uses GOP...

To control GOP, use the following VBoxManage command:

VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode N
Where N can be one of 0,1,2,3,4,5 referring to the 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024, 1440x900, 1920x1200 screen resolution respectively.

Comment: tried this command but mac runs at default size (1024x780). host is Windows 7 Proffesional amd guest is MacOS Sierra and VirtualBox is 5.2.6 (r120293). try and restart everything but nothing happened !

Comment: This one worked form me with macOS High Sierra: `VBoxManage setextradata "macOS" VBoxInternal2/EfiGraphicsResolution 1600x900`